REST API Compatibility Issue Between ColdFusion 2021 Updates 11 and 1
My REST API in ColdFusion runs properly on ColdFusion 2021 Update 1 but doesn't work on another server with ColdFusion 2021 Update 11. Is there a fix for this? It throws the error "404 - File or directory not found."
a sample code of one of my API is given below
<cffunction name="getcities" restpath="cities" access="remote" returntype="void" httpmethod="GET"
            produces="application/json">
            <cfset var result={}>
            <cfset var data=[]>
            <cfset response=structNew()>
                <cftry>
                    <cfset data=objUser.getCities()>
                    <cfset response.status="200">
                    <cfset result["success"]=true>
                    <cfset result["data"]=data>
                    <cfset response.content=result>
                        <cfcatch type="any">
                            <cfset result["success"]=false>
                            <!--- <cfset result["message"]="Problem executing database query " & #cfcatch["message"]#> --->
                            <cfset result["data"]= #cfcatch["message"]#>
                            <cfset response.status="200">
                            <cfset response.content=result>
                        </cfcatch>
                </cftry>

                <cfset restSetResponse(response)>

        </cffunction>

